# Can the MP9488 circuit be operated at 333mA output current?

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck, switching-regulator

I am looking to use the MP9488 as a buck Switching Regulator with a voltage output of 12V and output current of 333mA. In the application note it has an output current of 300mA.

As far as I understand it has an internal control which regulates switching frequency so that the peak current is 640mA, but I cannot find in the datasheet its maximum output current. So if anyone could help i would be very grateful!

Here is the datasheet: https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP9488/document_id/3748/

Comment: The datasheet can't give any number for the output current's average because the input can be in a very wide range which has a direct effect on the peak current. You need to calculate the peak current for the "minimum" input voltage, and the output voltage. Note that increasing the inductor will decrease the peak current.

Comment: The datasheet has a formula for the switching frequency such that the peak current is 640mA regardless of the inductor value. So I assume any output current which has a realistic switching frequency is fine. But I am not sure that is why I asked

Comment: Look at the bottom graph on page 6 of the datasheet. At 300mA out and 60V in, the junction temperature rise will be 115 or 120°C (multiply by 96/45 to get Tj rise), so if you need it to not fail at (say) 60°C ambient, even 300mA is nowhere near safe.. typically you'll hit absolute max junction temperature at only ~33°C Ta.